# My Documents view accross site collections, and be able to filter which ones are checkout

Tags: development

We have 16 000 site collections, some users collaborate in many site collections with documents.

We want to have a view or webpart on the root site collection, that shows all the documents uploaded or created for an specific user.

How can I achieve that?

2nd.  Let's suppose for a specific user the view or webpart will return 200 documents, but the user does not remember in which documents he was working on (checked out files).

It would be great if whatever I develop can filter out based on whether it's checked out or not.

Any tips?

Comment: There's a web part in the MySites that show the last 15 (IIRC) documents used by the user in any site across a Web App. Would this do?

Comment: but you said its on my sites only?

Comment: As far as I know, it's only available in that Site Template (My SharePoint Sites WP)

Comment: I'd agree with Dave though, the Lightning Conductor is a good option, probably not as slow as you'd imagine either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first option could be achieved using search.  I have done similar in SP2010 and used jQuery to pass the current user to the search web service.

The second option is more complex as search will ignore any files which have never been checked in.  There are some third party tools such as Lightning Conductor which can scan for files which have not been checked in across multiple site collections but I suspect with the number you have this will be rather slow.

Again, I have done this in 2010 using a PowerShell script which runs overnight and populates a list with all the checked out files, where they are and who has them checked out.  This means I can then have a little web part which queries the list to present the information to users.  Of course, it has to be accepted that this is not real time but it does achieve the aim.

Comment: its sp 2013, does that change the possible solution? maybe with the content search web part?

Comment: Yep - that is certainly an option with 2013.